# Build a function that accepts a Class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a function that would take a class definition as a parameter in order to switch on it's name

This is just to simplify my tests by creating one function that can generate data based on a given class

```
getMockDataForClass(c: Class, override){
   if(c === Person){ return getPersonMockData(override)}
   if(c === Dog){ return getDogMockData(override)}
...
}
```

so that I can write test like:

```
it('should process a persons information', ()=>{
   const p = getMockDataForClass(Person)
...
})

it('should compare 2 persons', ()=>{
   const p = getMockDataForClass(Person)
   const p2 = getMockDataForClass(Person, {name: 'Jane'})
})
```

However there doesn't seem to be a type of `class` which would allow me to make this generic

Comment: According to [this article](https://2ality.com/2020/04/classes-as-values-typescript.html) it's `Class<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want a "newable" type here?

```
type Class = {
    new (...args: unknown[]): unknown
    name: string // if you need it
}
```

Which works as you may expect:

```
class Person { person = true }
class Dog { dog = true }

function getMockDataForClass(c: Class, override: Class){
   if(c === Person) { return override}
   if(c === Dog){ return override }
   return c
}

getMockDataForClass(Person, Dog)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5KgXigbwFBT1AOwgHcoAKAOioQCcBzJALigFcCBrAge2IIG0AugEpmbTjwK58BBAFsIzJMBoBLAnSgB6TVBUAzKCC4tCECABNdwbAF9s2AMaIUUAAoQaSLgSxRIn73QoZRZoOydkVAARLg1MKHNYoJCw+z02B2AVQLoIYABZLgd2KIRgBAAxLhp4SLIHZlqUABooLgA3D1VzBVhnJCEcfH169DQMdwCCIV8aPJYaHw6ulR67Yb1R8YwYukGoOeAFpc6abtT8Q+OoB1t7XIKikrLK6qakMkmvAlbdoSA)

---

If you want the second argument to be an instance of the class that is the first argument, then you need to capture the class constructor as a generic parameter. And then the `override` is an instance of that class.

For instance:

```
type Class = {
    new (...args: any[]): unknown
}

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class Dog {
    constructor(public breed: string) {}
}

function getMockDataForClass<T extends Class>(c: T, override: InstanceType<T>){
  //implementation...
}

getMockDataForClass(Person, {name: 'John'}) // fine
getMockDataForClass(Dog, {breed: 'Terrier'}) // fine
getMockDataForClass(Person, {breed: 'Terrier'}) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=57&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5KgXigbwFBT1AOwgHcoAKAOioQCcBzJALigQJAG0BdASmYFcCAawIB7YgWwBfbNgDGiFFAAKEGkhEEs2AJCyNSYDT6zgImmTB8ARnACWswggC2EZgZq2CdblmnS5CqgAIiJ0Wrr6hsam5pY29lBWNBAQACZuhp7evlIyAGYCJrYaUHQQwACyIrKCQQjACABiZvDISAA8ACpQEAAewBAEqaitKAB8ZLLMnQA0UCIAbqoeqa5QAJIEBqyyEJ3gEF1j3Dj4tnmT6GgYKmoaPphQycB8NJqLy7ar0mcXDtcYELeR7PV7vJY0FbQH54UFvKCyXLYMqVaq1epNFqBMi3dQEOaYAjONYAcgAUiIABYEEmSHwAenpUDynggyPKVRqdQazRooyQZCBBKSKXSUBJnU+qlpDKZLKI7NRXIxvP5ONUeOFyTSzAlUpoMqgjJ6kLMQA)

Comment: This nearly worked but I couldn't get the return type to behave 

```

Comment: I know, stackoverflow prevent editing a comment for 5 min :( 

This nearly worked but I couldn't get the return type to behave, I couldn't get the returned class to be of the same type as the inputed: ` getMockDataForClass(Person, {name: 'John'})` should return type Person

Comment: See my update which shows how to type the second argument as an instance of the class that is the first argument.